# How to find a .TTF font that contains a certain glyph?

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, prawn, glyph

Does anyone have suggestions on finding a `.ttf` font that contains − ? This is neither - or –.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you would e.g. specify (in the question, not in comments) the Unicode Codepoint about which you are talking. There are several unicode fonts around.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, most of the common font families such as **Time new Romans** or **Calibri** do have the dash or underscore glyph.But to be sure you can see your system's font and see if the font you are going to use dose have these glyphs or not!

See [this](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Calibri/) font, for instance.